# MCP23017 not causing interrupts using a normally open switch on power up

Tags: digital-logic, switches, netduino

I'm working on a project where I am using two 4x4 button pads. I would need to use two MCP23017 for input interrupts to support the 32 buttons. I am using a Netduino and I'm coming across an issue that I'm uncertain if its software related or hardware related.

I am using [this website as a guide](https://christianloris.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/netduino-plus-2-with-mcp23017-2-reading-writing-using-the-i2c-bus/) to understand and configure the MCP23017 and I'm following all the steps, including the diagram below:

[image: diagram]

The diagram shows the address as set, SDA and SCL have a resistor, reset is biased, a pin on the Netduino is set to handle the interrupt, and a microbutton is used to test the interrupt functionality.

I set the MCP23017 pin for the switch as input, set it to use a pull up resistor, then set the pin as an interrupt. The pin on the Netduino is set to use a pull up resistor as well and to cause interrupts when low. This works perfectly fine **as long as the Netduino boots up with switch closed**. If the switch is open (as it is normally open) no interrupts ever fire. I need to start the Netduino while pressing the microbutton to get the desired behavior. I'm unsure as to what is causing this. I am exhibiting the same behavior as the person commenting on the bottom of [this page](https://christianloris.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/netduino-plus-2-with-mcp23017-3-advanced-interrupt-handling-intcap/).

Is there either a software or hardware solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

1.7.5
 INTERRUPT CONDITIONS
There are two possible configurations that cause
interrupts (configured via INTCON):

1.
Pins configured for interrupt-on-pin change
will cause an interrupt to occur if a pin changes
to the opposite state. The default state is reset
after an interrupt occurs and after clearing the
interrupt condition (i.e., after reading GPIO or
INTCAP). For example, an interrupt occurs by
an input changing from ‘1’ to ‘0’. The new initial
state for the pin is a logic 0 after the interrupt is
cleared.

2.
Pins configured for interrupt-on-change from
register value will cause an interrupt to occur if
the corresponding input pin differs from the
register bit. The interrupt condition will remain as
long as the condition exists, regardless if the
INTCAP or GPIO is read.